# Navigation jquery plugin will not act as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make my jQuery nav work, but it won't act like I want it to. It's a plugin called `kwicks`. I want there to be text when the nav slides out.

I will put my [HTML and CSS in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KaKnp/), and I will give the link of the [test page of the site](http://Cyberiadesign.be/Test), that way you can take a look into the coding.

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<ul id="kwickslist" class='kwicks kwicks-horizontal'> 
    <li id='panel-1'> 
        <div class="kwicks_inner_inner"> 
            <div class="navimage"><a id="index2" href="index.html">test</a></div> 
            <div class="smallText"> <p>Cyberia Design.</p></div> 
        </div> 
    </li> 
    <li id='panel-2'>
        <div class="kwicks_inner"> 
            <div class="navimage"><a id="about2" href="about.html">test</a></div> 
            <div class="smallText">About.</div> 
        </div> 
    </li> 
    <li id='panel-3'> 
        <div class="kwicks_inner"> 
            <div class="navimage"><a id="work2" href="work.html">test</a></div> 
            <div class="smallText">Work.</div> 
        </div> 
    </li> 
    <li id='panel-4'> 
        <div class="kwicks_inner"> 
            <div class="navimage"><a id="contact2" href="contact.html">test</a></div> 
            <div class="smallText">Contact.</div> 
        </div> 
    </li> 
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.kwicks {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.kwicks > * {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.kwicks.kwicks-processed > * {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.kwicks-horizontal > * {
    float: left;
}
.kwicks-horizontal > :first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.kwicks-vertical > :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.kwicks {
    width: 515px;
    height: 100px;
}
.kwicks > li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /* overridden by kwicks but good for when JavaScript is disabled */
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#panel-1 { 
    background-color: #141414; 
}

#panel-2 { 
    background-color: #141414; 
}
#panel-3 { background-color: #141414; }
#panel-4 { background-color: #141414; }

#kwickslist li { 
    float: left; 
    width: 75px; 
    height: 50px; 
} 
#kwickslist .kwicks_inner { 
    width: 200px; 
} 
#kwickslist .navimage {  
    height: 50px; 
    float: left; 
} 
#kwickslist .smallText { 
    display: none; 
    text-align: center; 
    width: 50px; 
    color: white; 
    font-size: 10px; 
    margin-top: 5px; 
    float: right; 
} 
#kwickslist li.active.smallText { 
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the text-indent property on the 'a' tags back to '0' when they are hovered over as currently they are still set to '-9999px' on hover.

Probably need to set the colour on them to something like white too.

Also add this to your css:

```
ul#kwickslist li:hover .kwicks_inner_inner .smallText {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, I just get the link text, not the text when the menu item scrolls out.

Comment: I've amended my answer above - do that too and it should display the other text too.